# Foundation Top Bar Menu on Medium Screens

Tags: navigation, zurb-foundation

Fairly new to using foundation and I've been trying to figure out how to display the hamburger menu on medium and small screens only. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<!-- TOP BAR---------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <div class="contain-to-grid"> 
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
              <ul class="title-area">
                   <li><a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo-top.png" alt="" class="branding"></a></li>

                <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
                <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
              </ul>

              <section class="top-bar-section">
                <!-- Right Nav Section -->
                <ul class="right">
                   <li><a href="#guides">Test</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#gallery">Test</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#boats">Test</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#rates">Test</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#contact">CTest</a></li>
                </ul>
              </section>
         </nav>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick way would be to add the class `hide-for-large` to your first div or to the nav.

E.g.,

`<div class="contain-to-grid hide-for-large">`
or
`<nav class="top-bar hide-for-large" data-topbar role="navigation">`